# How to convert IQueryable<IList<AnimeTitle>> to IQueryable<AnimeTitle>

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, iqueryable

I need to get a collection by id, it has `IList<AnimeTitle> AnimeTitles`, which I need to convert to `IQueryable<AnimeTitle>` and project into `BriefTitleVW` to end up with `IQueryable<BriefTitleVW>`.

In the sample code, I do the conversion using AutoMapper `ProjectTo<BriefTitleVM>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)`, but this is not possible because this method can only convert `IQueryable<AnimeTitle>` to `IQueryable<BriefTitleVM>`.

So it comes down to converting `IQueryable<IList<AnimeTitle>>` to `IQueryable<AnimeTitle>`.

Question: how to do that?

```
var titles = await _dbContext.AnimeCollections
                             .Where(c => c.Id == request.CollectionId && c.UserId == request.UserId)
                             .Select(c => c.AnimeTitles)
                             .ProjectTo<BriefTitleVM>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
```

Comment: Change the Select to SelectMany. If it won't run because it "cannot be translated" you can ToList the Where then call SelectMany on the ToList to do the unpacking client side; the same amount of data is coming out the db

Comment: @Caius Jard, man, thank you so much, it would have taken me a long time to find a solution. In the end I added SelectMany and everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change:

```
.Select(c => c.AnimeTitles)
```

To:

```
.SelectMany(c => c.AnimeTitles)
```

When you have a "list of lists of X" (you have a list of `AnimeCollection` objects inside `db.AnimeCollections`, and each `AnimeCollection` has a list of `AnimeTitle` objects in its `AnimeTitles`) you can turn it into a straight "list of X" by using SelectMany. SelectMany, conceptually does this:

```
List<AnimeTitle> result = new();
foreach(AnimeCollection c in db.AnimeCollections)
  result.AddRange(c.AnimeTitles);
return result;
```

So your general pattern is to feed `.SelectMany` with a lambda that chooses a collection on each object in a list, and it churns out a single list of all the items in all the collections

```
//one list of all child items
parentCollection.SelectMany(item => item.ChildCollection)
```